# Statistics: Quantify Scatter Plot presenting an "upper limit"

Tags: correlation, data-visualization, interpretation, pearson-r, scatterplot

When I plot my data-set on a scatter plot I see a complex correlation that I don't know well how to quantify: the points present a kind of upper limit, a "cap". Note that the X marginal distributions have similar mean value (around Y=0.05 ), as evident in the colored 2D histogram. But I want to quantify numerically the trend of the "cap function". What can I do? Thanks [image]
[image]